# My first flask app - how to pass html input to python without a database?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I created an app that moves the largest files from the chosen folder to a new folder for inspection. I tried to create an interface for it using django and when I asked my friend, who is fluent in python about the architecture, he said I don't really need a database, so I should rather try flask.
In a flask tutorial, I found the guy is actually using SQLAlchemy and is creating a database. How can I pass HTML input to my python omitting database?
The pure python app I have already created works just fine without any database.

HTML input section:

```html
{% block body %}
  <h1>Your computer can run faster today</h1>
  <p>You just need to remove the largest files from some of your folders. It's easy with this small project. Enjoy :)</p>
  <form>
    <label for="fname">Path to the folder you want to remove largest files from:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <label for="lname">Path to the folder you want to put your removed files for inspection</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Python input section:

```
print("Type a path to the folder you want to remove the largest files from") 
path1 = os.path.abspath(input())
print("Type a path to create a folder for the largest files to inspect them before removing")
path2 = os.path.abspath(input())
path3 = path2 + '/ToBeRemoved'
```

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 - maybe my understanding of the topic wasn't so thorough to use the proper keywords to find the answer? Why do I get negative reputation for being a noob?

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just made it clearer for other users to understand your question by re-formatting your code.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic Flask app to achieve this will look something like this.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def remove_large_files():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        path_from = request.form.get('fname')
        path_to = request.form.get('lname')

        if path_from and path_to:
            # process your files
            
            # return a response

    return render_template('template.html')
```

Replace `template.html` by the template that contains your form.

Refer to the [`Request` object docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#the-request-object) for more info.